# Unable to use bootable USB make by CMD in legacy mode

Tags: command-line, boot, usb, uefi, legacy

I need to make a bootable usb which has a TinycoreOS by command without using rufus. I follow the SOP as below:

https://www.chanhvuong.com/2634/create-bootable-usb-flash-drive-with-diskpart-command-line-utility/

I can boot in UEFI mode. But when I open the csm and change boot-mode to the legacy only, my bootable usb can't be identified as a boot device. It will show can't find any operating system. Is there anything I just ignored?

Update my detail demand-

What I want to do is to make a bootable usb which has a TinyCoreOS and can implement in both Legacy/UEFi mode. In addition, I only can use CMD or No-UI programming to make the usb. Is that possible?

thx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Why are you following a Windows 7 post to create a Linux boot (TinycoreOS)? You need to add many more details to explain what you're doing.

Comment: They recommend using their own tool: https://sourceforge.net/projects/core2usb/

Comment: All OSes support EFI boot, with the [_sole purpose_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#CSM_booting) of CSM [Legacy] Mode being to allow OSes that didn't support EFI boot circa <2017 to EFI boot. In other words, **CSM Mode should never be enabled** since it's only purpose nowadays is to boot a legacy OptionRom and motherboard manufacturers have already begun removing that defunct option from their board's UEFI firmware _(if an OPROM needs to be booted to, CSM Mode should be re-disabled once exiting it)_.  Disable CSM Mode and the USB can be booted.

Comment: What file system? Some PC's cannot boot from exFAT, for example, only FAT32.

Comment: What I want to do is to make a bootable usb which has a TinyCoreOS and can implement in both Legacy/UEFi mode.  In addition, I only can use CMD or No-UI programming to make the usb. Is that possible?

Comment: UEFI booting works because it's file based, so extracting all the files from a tarball / image could be all that you need to do. For BIOS/legacy booting, boot code writing to the MBR and so on is pretty much always required.

Comment: @TomYan So is there anyway to use CMD to let bootable usb can be used in the legacy mode?

Comment: I can't rule out all the possibilities, after all there's grub2win whatsoever. As long as you can install a bootloader (for BIOS/CSM; that can boot the kernel) and configure it properly, it is possible for you to make it happen.

Comment: Apparently there's an official build of grub for windows too: https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/grub/ (not sure about the difference between that and grub2win)

Comment: note that you want to be really careful when you use any of these since they could by default install to your main hard drive. Better do more research on how to specify the drive to install to first.